# Communication between a Windows mobile 6.5 app and a Winform app

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6.5, inter-process-communicat

First, a WinCE app scannes several barcodes and submit, then a winform app on a PC gets all the barcodes and generates some files and inserts some info into an Oracle database.

So what is the most reliable and easiest approach to realize the communication between a Windows mobile 6.5 app and a Winform app in my scenario?  I am really anxious to achieve the above requirements. Thank you in advance!

Comment: We might need a little more context. Where are the phone and PC? Physically connected (via USB or something else)? On the same network? Are you expecting to have to use 4G to get the phone to communicate?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Have you read up on any communication protocols that you think are possible? People are more likely to help if you can show that you have put in some effort yourself.

Comment: Sorry about my carelessness. It is a hand held barcode scanner device running Windows mobile 6.5. The device and the windows PC are connected by a same wireless lan.

Comment: I have already tried a Web service approach: running a Web service on the PC and call it from the hand held device. It is so slow and user has to wait synchronously.

Comment: Webservices, in this regard, is anything but slow... I use a webservice over a 4mbit internet line, with VERY good speed and performance.. It can only be 10 fold better on LAN (even if Wifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Mobile App (Store records) - > DB on LAN < - Windows App (Collect)
- Mobile App (calls functions) - > WCF hosted in Windows App (Accepts mobile app input)

As in my comments on your original question.. WCF should do great here... its plentyfull fast and capable enough to transmit some barcodes... If your implementation is slow, you are probably doing something wrong...